# Samba client prohibits to copy filenames with special characters eg %7C (pipe) or other. What to do?

Tags: linux, samba

Samba client prohibits to copy filenames with special characters eg %7C (pipe) or other. both machines are linux driven. What to do?

I would like to retain filenames as it is.
I have modified /etc/samba/smb.conf to include in global section this in both computers and restarted samba service in both computers too.

```
[global]
mangled names = no
unix charset = UTF-8
```

What else I must do?
Note my filenames may contain chinese characters, enter, space, new lines etc.

I did the operation through Dolphins file manager, as drag & drop.

UPDATE

I send the files as a tar container file.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing full path and/or filename in single or double quotes?

Comment: I do it from dolphins file browser. I can normally copy them from same HDD to another of same machine but not across machines

Comment: I am going to zip content and send them as zip file

Comment: You could also try another file manager, e.g., PCman FM, https://sourceforge.net/projects/pcmanfm/. However, when writing your question, you should include that you're using *drag and drop* in a file manager, rather than from Terminal or shell. BTW, you can *zip* (or tar) a file, or a few files, and when transferred and unarchived, filename(s) should be unchanged.